# NSURLConnection Memory

Tags: memory, nsurlconnection

I have a problem in NSURLConnection. i.e.

I have created a global instance of NSURLConnection.

```
NSURLConnection *con;
```

So when i am using it any where i am checking firstly that whether con is available if it is i just release it and nil the pointer and then make a new instance of that

```
if (con){
[con release]];
con = nil;
}
con = [NSURLConnection initwithRequest: request delegate:self];
```

is it the proper way to handle the memory problem. Since sometime my project crash (i think due to it.). If not than what will bw a proper way to handle memory problems?

Thank You.

Comment: "I have created a global instance of NSURLConnection." - that's your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply H2CO3. You mean one should always use local NSURLConnection variable ?

Comment: I'm saying that the need for global variables almost always indicates a code design problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a NSURLConnection property as:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) NSURLConnection connection;
```

You can kick off the connection as:

```
self.connection =[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request
                                                 delegate:self
                                         startImmediately:NO];
[self.connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
[self.connection start];
```

There is an example on [github](https://github.com/hrchen/ExamplesForBlog).